# Is there such a term as "modern street food era"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I wonder if there is such a word as "modern street food era"? I do realize that street food was popular in ancient Rome and in Medieval Times, but can we just add the adjective "modern" to refer to our days when street food is so very popular?

Comment: Hello, kinga, welcome to ELU! This question is clear, but would be better if you would show what you have found in sources you have [searched](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badjectives%5D+cumulative), as [how to ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) explains. This helps us to know where exactly to start answering. Cheers!

Comment: What does _modern street food era_ actually mean? When the pizza was invented, it was modern street food.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *Modern* in the West can start as far back as 1300 or as recently as 10 years ago, so you must provide adequate context for framing. In the U.S., some might use "modern" street food to refer to 19th-century introductions like hot dog stands and popcorn carts, but others would use it to contrast the 2010s food truck boom against the older types.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your comments. I did use some search engines (e.g.Google) but this expression simply did not come up. I do not know if it exists at all. I was asked to translate a text and that is how I've come across it. What I am trying to describe is the 21st century streetfood boom ( hence modern) - the text is about fancy burgers which look and taste great...Thanks for your help and suggestions!